# Understanding Lambda

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

```
X = 5
L = list(map(lambda x: 2**X, range(7)))
print (L)
```

... I'm expecting this to return:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

...instead, it returns:

```
[32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive, so `lambda x: 2**X` means: take an argument, call it (lowercase) `x`, ignore it completely, and return 2 to the power of global variable (uppercase) `X`.

Comment: AH! Proves that I'm a real beginner! :P Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Python is case-sensitive. `x` and `X` are different variables.

By the way, perhaps an easier way to construct `L` would be

```
L=[2**x for x in range(7)]
```

Or, if you'd like to use `map` and `lambda`, then

`L=map(lambda x: 2**x, range(7))`

suffices. `map` returns a list, so you do not have to wrap the expression in a `list(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `L = list(map(lambda x: 2**x, range(7)))` once.  You were using `X` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. It should be:

```
# Upper case X refers to 5
list(map(lambda x: 2**x, range(7)))
```